# Background image no longer fits to screen now that project is in php files

Tags: php, css, html, custom-background

When my project was still coded as html files, the background images of my sections of my landing page fit the screen, but since changing it to php files to upload to wordpress these sections leave blank space on either side as well as above.

This is the CSS corresponding to it

```
#landing-section {

    padding-top: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
    background-image: url(images/landing-section-image.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    height: 100vh;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Check the generated source—does WordPress insert new `<div>` tags around your `#landing-section` element?

Comment: No, the source is identical other than what <?php wp_head();?> adds to it

Comment: It sounds like your theme (or some plugin's) CSS is overriding your styles somehow. You can inspect the `#landing-section` element to see what styles it's inheriting.